# Javascript : How do I call the array index of the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I have a problem when you change the string in order to invoke an array in javascript, please help me,

I have had a array:

```
var fruit=['Apple','Banana','Orange'];
```

and I have data string from mysql:

example: `var string = '0,2';`

How to display an array of `fruit` which corresponds to the `var string`?

(Thanks for the help)

Comment: What does `var string = '0,2';` represent in your `fruit` array, `apple` or `orange` or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `split()` the string to get an array of indexes instead of a string of indexes :

```
var indexes = '0,2'.split(','); //use the ',' char to split the string
```

Now, you have to pick fruits values corresponding to each index in the new indexes array create just before.

```
var res = []; //The new Array to contains new fruits

indexes.forEach(function(index) { //loop over fruit indexes we want

  res.push(fruit[index]); //Add the juicy fruit :)

});
```

And you got the new array (`res`) with the juicy fruits :)

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fieldset/2srchotr/)

**EDIT:**

Or, a shorter/nicer solution (thanks to **Xotic750**)
(the second argument of the map function specify the context (this))

```
var ids = '0,2';
var fruits = ['Apple','Banana','Orange'];

fruits = ids.split(',').map(function(index) {
    return this[index];
}, fruits);
```

Comment: You're welcolme ! It was a pleasure :)

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would seem the logical choice `'0,2'.split(',').map(function(index) { return this[index]; }, ['Apple','Banana','Orange']);`

Comment: @Xotic750 Cool solution ! I had it to my main post to complete the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work or not, but this is what I could think of:

```
var x = [];
for (var i = 0; i>=string.length; i+=2) {
 x.push(fruit[string[i]]);
}
```

But use only even numbers as a comma is also present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the `string` into an array by using the `Split()` method:

```
var myArray = string.split(",");
```

Then you can loop over the array and use its values as indexes in the `fruit` array. For example, the first fruit will be:

```
fruit[myArray[0]];
```